# VBA if else doesn't return correct values

Tags: vba, if-statement

Trying to return a L, M, H value based on the values of two inputs. Here is what I have:

```
If (80 <= x <= 120 And y > 120) Or (x > 120 And y > 120) Or (x > 120 And 80 <= y <= 120) Then
    CDI = "H"

ElseIf (x < 80 And y <= 120) Or (x < 120 And y < 80) Then
    CDI = "L"

ElseIf (x < 80 And y > 120) Or (80 <= x <= 120 And 80 <= y <= 120) Or (x > 120 And y < 80) Then
    CDI = "M"

End If
```

The values being returned aren't what I need. For example, (0,291) returns H when it should clearly be M. Why?

Answer (score 3):

The conditions with the variable in the middle (even if they are acceptable to the VBA interpreter) are almost certainly not going to produce the result you expect.  Change all such conditions to the equivalent of the form:

```
variable condition constant
```

Example: Change

```
80 <= x <= 120
```

to

```
x >= 80 and x <= 120
```

Comment: DUH, thanks so much that fixed it. I'm new to VBA but made the poor assumption it could act as python does. Thanks again!

Comment: @Robert, so it handles the `variable condition variable` as an `or` statement?

Comment: @Elias: I think it probably has more to do with order of operations, and the way results of calculations are intepreted as boolean values, but I haven't really checked.

Comment: I think you're right. `False < 120 = True`, because `False = 0` And `True = 1`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
If (x >= 80 And x <= 120 And y > 120) Or (x > 120 And y > 120) Or (x > 120 And y >= 80 And y <= 120) Then
    CDI = "H"

ElseIf (x < 80 And y <= 120) Or (x < 120 And y < 80) Then
    CDI = "L"

ElseIf (x < 80 And y > 120) Or (x >= 80 And x <= 120 And y >= 80 And y <= 120) Or (x > 120 And y < 80) Then
    CDI = "M"

End If
```